# BackboneJS model.fetch() unsuccessful

Tags: backbone.js, model, fetch

**Hi I have this model :**

```
window.shop = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    console.log('initializing shop');
  },
  urlRoot: "shopData.json",
});
```

**and then i go :**

```
var myShop = new shop();
myShop.fetch({
    success: function (model, resp){
        console.log(resp);
    },
    error: function (model, resp){
        console.log("error retrieving model");
}}, {wait: true});
```

**now I'm always getting the error message - never reaching success :-(**

thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you tell what response you are receiving ? If server isn't returning proper `json` object, it will always go in `error` callback.

Comment: Which version of Backbone are you using? Please mention the version number. If you are using one from the git repo, please link to the commit. Reason I ask, `0.9.2` version of Backbone doesn't accept two arguments.

Comment: damm that's exactly what i am using ! - so what now ? what is the correct way to do this ?
@AmithGeorge

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:**

As per your comment the server is sending the proper response but Backbone is still calling the error function. Add the following line at the beginning of the error callback:

```
error: function (model, resp){
    console.log('error arguments: ', arguments);
    console.log("error retrieving model");
}
```

The first line should print an array of objects. The first element in the array should the jqXhr object, the second should be a string representation of the error. If you click on the first object, the dev tools will let you inspect its properties. Read up on the properties of the object here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR.

Using that information you can verify if the jQuery is receiving an error from the server.

If there is no server side error, then check the value of the `responseText` property. That holds the string data returned from the server. `$.ajax` will try to parse that data into JSON. Most likely the parsing is throwing an error and the error handler is being raised instead.

Copy the response text and paste it into http://jsonlint.com/. Verify that the response sent from the server is valid JSON. Do update your question with the output of the `console.log` statement and the `responseText` property of the `jqxhr` object.

-x-x-x-

You seem to be using the model independently. As the per the documentation, http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url,

> Generates URLs of the form: "/[urlRoot]/id"

That means, you are making a request to `shopData.json/id`. Also, you haven't specified the id.

Insert a `console.log(myShop.url())` before the `myShop.fetch()`. Let us know whats the output. Also, possibly share the details of the ajax request as seen in Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools. I am interested in two things, the request url and the response returned by the server.  (http://getfirebug.com/network)

Comment: console.log(myShop.url()) outputs : "shopData.json"

Comment: response returned from the ajax is correct. i am getting : 
{
 'shopId'       : 'shId0',
 'ownerId'      : 'ownrId0',
 'title'        : 'Shop Title',
 'accountType'  : 'free',
 'logo'         : null,
 'aboutPicture' : null
}

Comment: Btw, if the server is sending invalid response, update your question to include the server side language used, its version and the relevant server side code that outputs the said invalid json.